# Getting SSL and other errors while recording iOS native app with Jmeter

Tags: ios, jmeter, jmeter-4.0

**Jmeter logs :**

```
2018-11-28 18:35:49,906 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Valid alias found for :root_ca:
2018-11-28 18:35:49,907 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Valid alias found for :intermediate_ca:
2018-11-28 18:35:49,907 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: Creating Daemon Socket on port: 8080
2018-11-28 18:35:49,910 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: Test Script Recorder up and running!
2018-11-28 18:35:53,931 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: [58628] Creating entry itunes.apple.com in C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\proxyserver.jks
2018-11-28 18:35:56,430 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58628]  KeyStore for SSL loaded OK and put host 'itunes.apple.com' in map with key (itunes.apple.com)
2018-11-28 18:35:56,972 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58630]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'gateway-india.icloud.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:35:56,996 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58631]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'gateway-india.icloud.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:35:57,031 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58629]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'configuration.apple.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:35:58,826 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58633]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api.branch.io'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:35:58,856 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58635]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'sandbox.itunes.apple.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:35:58,868 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58632]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'play.googleapis.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:35:58,910 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58636]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'iid.googleapis.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:35:58,911 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58634]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'settings.crashlytics.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:35:58,913 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58637]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'e.crashlytics.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:36:02,863 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58628]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'itunes.apple.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:36:03,743 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [49199]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'ws-80F09F2C-9E4A-4559-AF1D-D564B1252B3A.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: no cipher suites in common
2018-11-28 18:36:04,311 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58638]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api.branch.io'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:36:04,372 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58639]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'cloudconfig.googleapis.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:36:04,384 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58641]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api-80f09f2c-9e4a-4559-af1d-d564b1252b3a.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:36:04,397 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58640]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'e.crashlytics.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:36:08,859 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [49200]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'ws-80F09F2C-9E4A-4559-AF1D-D564B1252B3A.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: no cipher suites in common
2018-11-28 18:36:08,862 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58642]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api.branch.io'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:36:08,921 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58643]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api-80f09f2c-9e4a-4559-af1d-d564b1252b3a.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:36:13,387 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [49201]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'ws-80F09F2C-9E4A-4559-AF1D-D564B1252B3A.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: no cipher suites in common
2018-11-28 18:36:14,036 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58644]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api.branch.io'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:36:14,073 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58645]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api-80f09f2c-9e4a-4559-af1d-d564b1252b3a.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:36:16,943 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58646]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'gateway-india.icloud.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:36:18,524 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [49202]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'ws-80F09F2C-9E4A-4559-AF1D-D564B1252B3A.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: no cipher suites in common
2018-11-28 18:36:18,829 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58647]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api-80f09f2c-9e4a-4559-af1d-d564b1252b3a.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:36:23,314 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [49203]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'ws-80F09F2C-9E4A-4559-AF1D-D564B1252B3A.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: no cipher suites in common
2018-11-28 18:36:25,947 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58648]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api-80f09f2c-9e4a-4559-af1d-d564b1252b3a.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:36:25,963 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58649]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'gs-loc.apple.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:36:30,437 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [49204]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'ws-80F09F2C-9E4A-4559-AF1D-D564B1252B3A.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: no cipher suites in common
2018-11-28 18:36:31,943 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58650]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api-80f09f2c-9e4a-4559-af1d-d564b1252b3a.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:36:36,429 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [49205]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'ws-80F09F2C-9E4A-4559-AF1D-D564B1252B3A.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: no cipher suites in common
2018-11-28 18:36:38,010 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58651]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api-80f09f2c-9e4a-4559-af1d-d564b1252b3a.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:36:42,503 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [49206]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'ws-80F09F2C-9E4A-4559-AF1D-D564B1252B3A.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: no cipher suites in common
2018-11-28 18:36:43,780 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58652]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api-80f09f2c-9e4a-4559-af1d-d564b1252b3a.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:36:48,271 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [49207]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'ws-80F09F2C-9E4A-4559-AF1D-D564B1252B3A.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: no cipher suites in common
2018-11-28 18:36:49,967 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58653]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api-80f09f2c-9e4a-4559-af1d-d564b1252b3a.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:36:54,458 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [49208]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'ws-80F09F2C-9E4A-4559-AF1D-D564B1252B3A.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: no cipher suites in common
2018-11-28 18:36:57,057 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58654]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api-80f09f2c-9e4a-4559-af1d-d564b1252b3a.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:37:01,067 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder stopped
2018-11-28 18:37:01,546 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [49209]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'ws-80F09F2C-9E4A-4559-AF1D-D564B1252B3A.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: no cipher suites in common
2018-11-28 18:37:03,008 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [58655]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api-80f09f2c-9e4a-4559-af1d-d564b1252b3a.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:51:26,602 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Valid alias found for :root_ca:
2018-11-28 18:51:26,602 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Valid alias found for :intermediate_ca:
2018-11-28 18:51:26,603 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: Creating Daemon Socket on port: 8080
2018-11-28 18:51:26,605 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: Test Script Recorder up and running!
2018-11-28 18:52:30,700 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder stopped
2018-11-28 18:52:32,576 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [49172]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'ws-80F09F2C-9E4A-4559-AF1D-D564B1252B3A.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: no cipher suites in common
2018-11-28 18:52:32,666 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57586]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api-80f09f2c-9e4a-4559-af1d-d564b1252b3a.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:52:32,678 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57588]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api.branch.io'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:52:32,694 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57589]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'e.crashlytics.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:52:33,263 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57587]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'sandbox.itunes.apple.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:52:35,898 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Valid alias found for :root_ca:
2018-11-28 18:52:35,898 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Valid alias found for :intermediate_ca:
2018-11-28 18:52:35,898 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: Creating Daemon Socket on port: 8080
2018-11-28 18:52:35,900 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: Test Script Recorder up and running!
2018-11-28 18:52:45,043 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57597]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'sandbox.itunes.apple.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:52:45,073 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57598]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api.branch.io'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:52:45,084 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57596]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'play.googleapis.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:52:45,098 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57599]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'settings.crashlytics.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:52:45,481 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57600]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'iid.googleapis.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:52:45,576 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57601]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'e.crashlytics.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:52:47,194 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [49175]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'ws-80F09F2C-9E4A-4559-AF1D-D564B1252B3A.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: no cipher suites in common
2018-11-28 18:52:47,241 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57602]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api-80f09f2c-9e4a-4559-af1d-d564b1252b3a.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:52:49,743 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57603]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api.branch.io'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:52:50,052 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57604]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'cloudconfig.googleapis.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:52:50,141 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57605]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'e.crashlytics.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:52:51,730 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [49176]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'ws-80F09F2C-9E4A-4559-AF1D-D564B1252B3A.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: no cipher suites in common
2018-11-28 18:52:51,821 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57606]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api-80f09f2c-9e4a-4559-af1d-d564b1252b3a.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:52:54,351 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57607]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api.branch.io'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:52:56,309 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [49177]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'ws-80F09F2C-9E4A-4559-AF1D-D564B1252B3A.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: no cipher suites in common
2018-11-28 18:52:56,407 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57608]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api-80f09f2c-9e4a-4559-af1d-d564b1252b3a.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:52:58,965 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57609]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api.branch.io'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:53:00,894 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [49178]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'ws-80F09F2C-9E4A-4559-AF1D-D564B1252B3A.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: no cipher suites in common
2018-11-28 18:53:01,017 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57610]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api-80f09f2c-9e4a-4559-af1d-d564b1252b3a.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:53:05,504 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [49179]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'ws-80F09F2C-9E4A-4559-AF1D-D564B1252B3A.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: no cipher suites in common
2018-11-28 18:53:05,725 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57611]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api-80f09f2c-9e4a-4559-af1d-d564b1252b3a.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
2018-11-28 18:53:10,214 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [49180]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'ws-80F09F2C-9E4A-4559-AF1D-D564B1252B3A.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: no cipher suites in common
2018-11-28 18:53:10,315 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder stopped
2018-11-28 18:53:10,331 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [57612]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api-80f09f2c-9e4a-4559-af1d-d564b1252b3a.sendbird.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake
```

**What I am using** :

1. Jmeter 4.0
2. iPhone 6
3. iOs version 12.1
4. Laptop os window 7
5. iphone is connected via cable as well as wifi

I setup basic controls for recording. It records fine when I open any website in safari browser from mobile But it gives me above error when try to record one of my native iOS app.

I took `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt`from bin folder, sent via email , download from email and install into iphone 6. It also shows that certificate is verified. Is that any issue with app or I am missing something in configuration.

I read lot of similar questions on `SO` and other sites but no question is for exact iOs recording so posting here.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have loaded the certificate from your email message you must then go into General>About>Certificate Trust Settings and switch the certificate trust setting on.